# Replace less than**(<)** and greater than**(>)** symbol in php with text

Tags: php

I searched for a while for a script, that could see the difference between an html tag and just < and > placed in the text, 
the reason is that I receive text from a database,
Which is inserted by an html form, and contains text and html tags, 
the text can contain < and >, so does the tags,
with htmlspecialchars you can validate your text to XHTML,
but you'll also change the tags, like `<b>` to `&lt;b&gt;`,
so I needed a script that could see the difference between those two...

Please solve my problem.

Comment: What is your current string? and What is your desired string?

Comment: Why not just use Regular Expressions? I mean HTML Tags can contain 0 spaces, but when they don't, then there must be other text like href="/".

Comment: Try this:- echo strip_tags($text);

Comment: @RaviHirani how does removing the tags alltogether (and the content inside them) solve OP's problem?

Comment: @DamienPirsy: My mistake. She wants to remove only two special characters < and > but not HTML tags. Sorry for above comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that…

- the **<** and **>** characters in html tags are **not embraced** with blank spaces,
- the same characters always **are embraced** by blank spaces in conditions, and
- in conditions these combinations exist **<**, **>**, **<=**, **>=**, **!<**, **!>**

…this could be a solution:

```
$result = preg_replace('/ ([!]{0,1})(<)([=]{0,1}) /', '$1&lt;$3', $string);
$result = preg_replace('/ ([!]{0,1})(>)([=]{0,1}) /', '$1&lt;$3', $result);
```

This is what the regular expression means for the **<** character:

```
\         # Match the character “ ” literally
(         # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [!]       # Match the character “!”
      {0,1}      # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
(         # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   <         # Match the character “<” literally
)
(         # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   [=]       # Match the character “=”
      {0,1}      # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\         # Match the character “ ” literally
```